# Delete a configmap itself from Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, configmap

I am trying to delete a configmap from a k8s namespace .. i created the configmap using the command below

`kubectl -n namespacename create -f configmap.yaml`

checking the k8s cheat sheet https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/ i didn't find anything related .. kindly advise how to do that ?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

#### To delete `configmap` using configmap name:

```sh
# kubectl delete configmap  <configmap-name>  -n  <namespace-name> 
$ kubectl delete configmap    my-cofigmap     -n   namespacename
```

#### To delete `configmap` using configmap yaml file:

```sh
# kubectl delete -f <file-directory> -n <namespace-name>
$ kubectl delete -f  configmap.yaml  -n  namespacename
```

Comment: yah that works :) thanks .. small question if i deleted it while its used will it affect the running pods ?

Comment: @HanyHabib The data of the ConfigMap still stays mounted in the running Pods. However, if a Pod is recreated, it will not be able to find the ConfigMap and an error will result.

Answer (score 5):

You can delete a configMap by it's name. If you are unsure you can check the configMaps within a namespace by using:

```bash
kubectl get configmap -n namespacename`
```

once you have them you can run a delete command:

```bash
kubectl delete configmap <configmapname> -n namespacename
```

Answer (score 1):

Should work this way:

```
kubectl delete configmap <configmap-name> -n <namespace-name>
```

Your configmap's name should be defined in your `configmap.yaml` file.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way if you created the ConfigMap with a YAML file is to delete it by referencing the YAML file as well:

```
kubectl delete -n <namespacename> -f configmap.yaml
```